# How can I tail a log file and add command: word on every line before output in a different file?

Tags: bash, shell

trying to tail and grep certain logs with `$installingFil` and adding `Command:` word before output in `$DNLOG`file, but file is empty /private/tmp/DownLog.log
What will be the correct approach to echo "Command:" before every line.

I am not able to add/echo `"Command:"` word before every line which is output in  /private/tmp/DownLog.log

like:-

```
Command: bla bla   
Command: downloding finish
```

Scrip -

```
#!/bin/bash
downFil=$(tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep 'Downloading files of')
        
dLog="/private/tmp/DownLog.log"
        
if [ -f /var/log/system.log ]; then
 echo "Command:" "$downFil" >> "$dLog" # dLog is blank
else
 echo "Command: Please wait.." >> $dLog # this works fine
fi
```

Comment: Can you post an extract of /var/log/system.log along with exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I am trying to grep all lines which contain  "Downloading files of" from /var/log/system.log file and output in /private/tmp/DownLog.log" with starting  Command:
Example :- Command: Downloading files of bla bla bla clash
where "bla bla bla clash" is from downFil grip and echo

But i am not able to add "Command: " word before every line which is output in  /private/tmp/DownLog.log

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should try:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep 'Downloading files of' | sed 's/^/Command: /' >> /private/tmp/DownLog.log
```

Comment: @Skull: Raman Sailopal asked you to post a sample of your input and a sample of your output. Instead of that, you described the output you want. Please don't do that: it is easier for us to understand what you want with a sample of your input and your output.

Comment: You can combine the `grep` and `sed` commands into a single command: `sed '/Downloading files of/s/^/Command: /'`.

Comment: @Socowi  or rather `sed -n '/Downloading files of/s/^/Command: /p'`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Of course. Thank you for adding that missing `-n` and `/p`.